# __getitem__ empty tuple argument

Tags: python, class

I am making a tree class, and I want the `__getitem__` method to take a tuple parameter, so I use it like this:

```
t[1, 2, 3]
```

However, when I want to get the root value I need to give it an empty tuple, and when I do

```
t[]
```

I get a syntax error:

```
>>> t[]
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: You should post the code you have now, and the error message you're getting.

Comment: You need to *actually pass an empty tuple* - `t[()]`

Comment: @NickB it isn't getting as far as the OP's code, this would happen with any object you tried to index with empty brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `__getitem__` probably expects one argument, which is supposed to be a tuple.

When you call it like `t[1, 2, 3]`, the `,` operator creates the tuple. But there is no way Python interpreter could know you want a tuple in `t[]` (it looks like you were trying to pass no arguments to `__getitem__`). The `[]` opeartor syntax requires one expresion to be inside it, so you got `SyntaxError` (using function call syntax would result in `TypeError` in this case).

Use `t[()]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling it as `t[()]` and not `t[]`